# Parent-Child Indexes

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery

I have two (2) lists that I've connected by an "Control ID" field, using the Web Part connection - the thing is, when I update the Child list [using "New Item"], the Parent "Control ID" value does NOT carry over to the new Child item. M. Rackley has a blog-project that uses JavaScript, but it doesn't work for me.

I'd like use JavaScript/JQuery, because of the Content web part, but I can't find a sure-fire way that will update the Child list index when the new form is opened (to establish the relationship); any suggestions/source code would GREATLY appreciated.